# Problem with biblatex (and/or biblatex-mla) package(s) and @thesis entry type, as well as with @misc

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-mla

This is the MWE>

```
\documentclass[a4paper,notitlepage]{report}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@thesis{ludena2016,
    author = {Ludena Aranda, Lucía},
    title  = {El grupo Shangai y el exotismo en la novela argentina de las dos últimas décadas del siglo XX},
    type = {phd},
    institution = {Universidad Complutense de Madrid},
    year = {2016}
}
@misc{ludenaaranda2016,
    author = {Ludena Aranda, Lucia},
    title = {El grupo Shangai y el exotismo en la novela argentina de las dos últimas décadas del siglo \textsc{xx}},
    date = {2016},
    type = {Tesis Doctoral},
    organization = {Universidad Complutense de Madrid}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=mla, citestyle=authoryear, bibencoding=utf8, sorting=nty, language=auto, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish=spanish]{csquotes}
\usepackage[hyperindex, colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{language=auto}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}


\begin{document}

Según  \parencite{ludenaaranda2016} %\parencite{ludena2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The problem is with citing `\parencite{ludena2016}`. If I add this citation the pdflatex compiling last forever. On the other hand, if I use `\parencite{ludenaaranda2016}` the fields `type` and `organization` do not appear.

I have tried `institution` instead of `organization` but does not work either.

Moreover, I have change the backend to `bibtex` but this adds more problems.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Try `\AddToNoCaseChangeList{\bibstring}`. The mla style tries to capitalize the type and the code then chokes over the \bibstring command.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked perfectly.

Comment: This looks like it would be related to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1246.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same issue that was reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1246 and ultimately turned out to be a missing definition in `expl3` (https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1130). The definition was promptly added.

Update your system so that you have at least `L3 programming layer <2022-09-28>`. With that version of `expl3` the MWE again compiles without error.